# searching github api is returning inconsistent results

Tags: axios, github-api

I'm running a query with axios in an express server to get the top 3 repos where language = javascript:

```js
axios({
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'

  },
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
  params: {
    q: 'language:JavaScript',
    sort: 'stars',
    order: 'desc',
    per_page: 3
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

It's returning 3 different results each time.
What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is here:
[get the top 10 javascript/opensource repositories ranked by star using GitHub GraphQL Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251307/get-the-top-10-javascript-opensource-repositories-ranked-by-star-using-github-gr)

it has to do with github limiting how long any query can run.  you have to help it out by adding another qualifier like stars:>1600